# Let $f(x):= \sum^{\infty}_{-\infty} d_n e^{inx}$ for $x \in \mathbb R$. Find the Fourier series for $f$ and show uniform convergence against $f$.

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $\sum^{\infty}_{-\infty} |d_n| < \infty$ and define $f(x):= \sum^{\infty}_{-\infty} d_n e^{inx}$ for $x \in \mathbb R$.

Find the Fourier series for $f$ and show it converge uniformly on $\mathbb R$ aswell on $L^2$ against $f$.

How can I start on this exercise ? First of all I must determine $f$ ? - but this series is not an ordinary series ?

Secondly, I have the Fourier series of $f$ is defined as $$\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac 1 {2\pi} (\int^{\pi}_{-\pi} f(y) e^{-iny} dy)e^{inx}$$, but in order to compute this I must know the integral ?

Comment: You can use the definition of $f$ you have in your definition of Fourier series.  Now what orthogonality properties do you have for the integrals $\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{i n x} e^{i m x} dx$?

Comment: But I cannot move $e^{inx}$ into the integral ?

Comment: And can I just assume $f$ does converge ?

Comment: $f$ converges because $|d_n e^{i n x}| \le |d_n|$, and you can move $e^{ in x}$ into the integral because it doesn't depend on $y$.

Comment: Your series converges uniformly (actually absolutely) on the segment $[-\pi,\pi]$, so you can swap sum and integral and see easily that $d_n$ are actually $f$ fourier's coefficients, and $f$ is exactly defined as its fourier series, which thus also converges uniformly.

Comment: Can I use the theory of majorant series (Weierstrass' M-test) to determine the series converges uniformly, even thus the series starts at $- \infty$ and not $0$ or some other natural number ?